# Using output of a python expression in an if statement

Tags: bash, python

I want to use the output of a simple Python expression as a condition in an if statement. I know that

```
x=$(python3 -c "print('False')")
echo $x
```

will produce the output of `False`, so I don't understand why this produces always a `True` result:

```
test () {
    if [ $(python3 -c "print('$1')") ]
    then
        echo "True"
    else
        echo "False"
    fi
}

test False
```

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: [Understanding boolean operators in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105935/understanding-boolean-operators-in-bash-script)

Comment: _Always_? It sounds like you didn't test it, since it definitely doesn't _always_ print `True`. An empty or nonexisting argument would trigger the `else` path, and an argument with whitespace would be likely to give an error (unless it'd be a valid test in itself, that is). See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: Also, a `$1` containing a single quote could potentially inject _any Python code_ into the command.

Comment: @ilkkachu, true, I used a too strong quantifier. "Always" for those string cases without white spaces that I have tested it.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're right, it's probably the duplicate of that one. I wasn't aware that the command will return a string and not a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$(python3 -c "print('$1')")` is a *string* not a logical value, and `[ ... ]` is just testing whether the string is non-empty.

To make it work the way you expect, change the test to

```
if [ "$(python3 -c "print('$1')")" = "True" ]
```

BTW you should avoid using `test` as the name of your function(s) since that will mask the shell builtin `test`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that!

I used "test" here as a name just for the purposes of this post, normally I use other names.